# Laravel 5.2 - Autocomplete Suggest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i'm creating a input autocomplete suggest from list of my database, but i have some problem, my input show the suggest like the picture:

[image]

Problem: My controller show 10 items like i want, but the termns doesn't work well, because as you can see if i write my municipality "Milan" it doesn't suggest correctly, actually my controller is showing the first 10 item of my table.

[image]

MY CONTROLLER:

```
public function getData(Request $request) {
    $termn = $request->input('municipality');
    // controllo
    $data = Municipality::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$termn.'%')->take(10)
    ->get();
    $results = array();
    foreach($data as $v){
        $results[]=['id' => $v->id, 'value' => $v->name];
    }
    //return $results;
    return response()->json($results);
}
```

ROUTES

```
Route::get('getdata', 'PostController@getData');
```

JS

```
$('#searchname').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: $('#route-url').val(),
    select: function(e, ui){ 

        console.log(ui.item.id);// it work and show me id of item selected
    },
});
```

VIEW FORM

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="seller-Location">Municipality</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <input 
               type="text" 
               name="municipality"
               placeholder="comune"
               class="form-control input-md"
               id="searchname">
      <input type="hidden" id="route-url" value="{{ url('getdata') }}">
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i inserted dd($request->input('municipality')); in my controller but doesn't show me nothing! how can see what result is dd($request->input('municipality')); ?

Comment: try using the network tab of developer tool(inspect element) and see if you are hitting the right url... if url is right, try using `$request->get('municipality')` instead of `$request->input('municipality')`.

Answer (score 0):

If `dd` is empty, it's because there is no data for this key :)

Use `var_dump($request->all());` or `dd($request->all());`

You will have the lsit of all parameters available.
I can see on your javascript's code `source: $('#route-url').val(),`.
So, I guess you will have values like this:

If result of dd is:

- **'source' => '...'** Then, you will have to use $request->input('source')
- **0 => '...'** Then, source is an array. Maybe try with `source: {municipality: $('#route-url').val()}` ?
- If data is empty, then, you have another issue. Read the documentation/examples of the autocomplete library